# Efficiency of power converters

Tags: power, switches

Why is the efficiency of rectifers not 100% even when ideal switches are used for its modelling? In conducting state, the voltage across switches is 0, and during blocking state, the current is 0. So power loss in the switches must be 0. Where does the lost power go?
Assuming ideal switches without snubber circuits.

Comment: If you found an ideal switch (probably on mouser.com, they always have good stuff), why do you think you still have losses?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I assume OP is talking about theoretical simulations.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Actually I am talking about theoretical simualtion and calcuations.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere no way. if he had simulation, he would show us what he is talking about.

Comment: @SambitVatsyayan no way. if you had simulation, you would show us what you are talking about.

Comment: Hi! So, we have no idea of what modeling you're talking. Please specify what model, in which context, says you have limited efficiency. As it is now, your question is not complete enough to be understood!

Comment: The fact that your switch is ideal, meaning Ron = zero, Roff = infinite means that it **cannot** dissipate power. Either the power is dissipated elsewhere (resistors and/or non-lossless components) and/or there are weird things happening in your simulation.

Comment: There was an error in my understanding of rectifier efficiency. Actually the efficiency of an ideal rectifier is defined as the ratio of DC power output to AC power input. As the output of a rectifier is not pure dc, so not all of the input power is being converted to dc. So, the efficiency is not 100 percent. Its not that power is being dissipated, its just that not all of the power being delivered to the load is DC. There is a ripple factor associated with the dc output.

Comment: Now that sounds rather strange...

Comment: So the answer is "it's so by definition". Normally definition of efficiency is "Pout/Pin', but you are free to use anything you want.

Comment: @Arsenal Yes it does sound strange, but rectifier efficiency by definition gives the percentage of input power that is being delivered as DC power (and not the total power being delivered). Its a matter of definition, and efficiency in this case is not being defined as the conventional 'Pout/Pin'.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Yes, you are right, it's in the definition. It's not the conventional 'Pin/Pout', rather it's 'Pdc/Pac'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For those being confused like me, especially with the added comments, this is the relevant part taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier):

> Several ratios are used to quantify the function and performance of
>   rectifiers or their output, including transformer utilization factor
>   (TUF), conversion ratio (η), ripple factor, form factor, and peak
>   factor. The two primary measures are DC voltage (or offset) and
>   peak-peak ripple voltage, which are constituent components of the
>   output.
>
> Conversion ratio (also called "rectification ratio", **and confusingly,
>   "efficiency"**) η is defined as the ratio of DC output power to the
>   input power from the AC supply. Even with ideal rectifiers, the ratio
>   is less than 100% because some of the output power is AC power rather
>   than DC which manifests as ripple superimposed on the DC waveform. The
>   ratio can be improved with the use of smoothing circuits which reduce
>   the ripple and hence reduce the AC content of the output. Conversion
>   ratio is reduced by losses in transformer windings and power
>   dissipation in the rectifier element itself. **This ratio is of little
>   practical significance because a rectifier is almost always followed
>   by a filter to increase DC voltage and reduce ripple.** In some
>   three-phase and multi-phase applications the conversion ratio is high
>   enough that smoothing circuitry is unnecessary. In other circuits,
>   like filament heater circuits in vacuum tube electronics where the
>   load is almost entirely resistive, smoothing circuitry may be omitted
>   because resistors dissipate both AC and DC power,so no power is lost.

(emphasis mine)

So it would probably be better to name it conversion ratio and not efficiency even though it is a ratio of powers.